# If you exhale and sink, then crouch underwater, why will you bounce?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I don't understand the step under the red arrow. I'm assuming that the blue line isn't the ocean floor, for we're assuming "deep waters". [I happened upon this picture on Reddit](https://redd.it/fqwb9w).

1. After you "exhale and sink" and "crouch", why will you necessarily bounce?
2. What depth best befits the "Crouch and bounce"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After you "exhale and sink" and "crouch", why will you necessarily bounce?

You use your leg muscles to give momentum upwards by hitting the floor. The crouch is to give a maximum force up. Do not forget that the human body floats in salt water, so a liitle force goes a long way.

> What depth best befits the "Crouch and bounce"?

The image shows twice the size of a person.

In salt water one can always float on the back and breath until rescue comes, so I think this would be good advice for lakes and ponds  and swimming pools where the buoyancy is less and the human body sinks.